# Setting up Sentry (Raven) with Sail.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, sentry

I am quiet new to sails.js and currently trying to integrate sentry with it. I read up the following tutorial on it.

https://docs.sentry.io/clients/node/

But i am not able to register error on sentry if i use patchGlobal command, it works on local errors when i declare it env/production file but if i define it in other places it doesn't even register local errors.

I also tried integrating it as a middleware but i am not able to integrate it correctly since the link they have provided is for express.

https://docs.sentry.io/clients/node/integrations/express/

Any help would be really appreciated !

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end , i was able to use Winston to log errors using Sentry in Sails. Following is the link:

https://github.com/guzru/winston-sentry

Answer (score 0):

This might be a solution to your problem:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-sentry